# Ubuntu 22.04 How to cast the entire screen with sound

Tags: sound, 22.04, desktop-recording, chromecast

I recently updated my Ubuntu version to 22.04, and I would like to cast my desktop to Chromecast.

I tried the following things:

1. With Google Chrome I'm able to cast a browser tab. Sound and image works nice.
2. When you try to share desktop, I can see the image properly, but sound does not work.
3. I tried to use from GNOME desktop "Cast to TV" extension, but it seems it doesn't work with this Ubuntu version.
4. I tried with mkchromecast. After trying several commands, I only could cast image from my desktop. I couldn't cast the sound.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Does anyone with Ubuntu 22.04 have any alternative working method for casting desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the built-in Ubuntu screen-sharing feature? It's a little hidden, but it's there. Go to the settings, look for "Sharing" and give it a shot. If that doesn't work, you can always try using VLC to stream your desktop. It's a bit more complicated, but it will get the job done. Just follow the instructions on their website, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried screen-sharing feature (you were right, it is a little bit hidden). It seems it is made for sharing your desktop through a remote desktop client (remmina) and for sharing your media files through dlna client-server. This is not what I need. I would like use my chromecast as a screen mirroring (It worked fine in older ubuntu versions using cast screen choice of chrome). VLC is not a choice in my case. I tried the renderer choice for casting only the video I'm watching and it does not work either. I don't know why. I'm still looking for a solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Wayland by following the instructions in [How to enable/disable wayland on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop), which I'll highlight below:

1. Edit the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` with your favorite text editor (I'll use `nano`):

   ```
   nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```
2. Look for the line that says `#WaylandEnable=false` and uncomment it so that it looks as:

   ```
   WaylandEnable=false
   ```
3. Save the file and exit. In `nano` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
4. Restart GDM3 by running this command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart gdm3
   ```

   or reboot your system for the changes to take effect.
5. Login to Ubuntu 22.04 using Xorg by clicking on the gear button and selecting the *Ubuntu on Xorg* option before you login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNOME Network Displays, from link -- https://flathub.org/apps/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays

Comment: sadly GNOME Network Displays has several known issues and doesn't seem to work at all with 23.10